# How to effectively recover from lost of connection?

Tags: python, request, recover

I use 'requests' modular to get information from some given site with a relatively high frequency.
In fact I'd like to access the remote site every 10 seconds.

My codes are as following:

```
def get_response_without_ddos_suspect(request_url, timeout=10):
    while True:
        try:
            response = requests.get(request_url, timeout=timeout)
            print response
        except Exception as e:
            print e
        time.sleep(10)
```

The 'request_url' is some access api provided by the web site, so it's no problem.
I hope it works, but in fact the function failed to work sometimes.
I tried to capture the exceptions by printing them out to find it's just simple time out exception.
But my function never gets response any longer.
I feel like the function is waiting for some response that never comes!

However, when I manually restart the function, it starts to get response again.
So, I'm really puzzled and have no idea what happen.
This problem has been puzzling me several days but I failed to solve it myself after Googling and looking for solutions in Stackoverflow for days.
How to keep accesing the site while avoiding no longer getting data after some exception happens.
Since it can recover by manully restart the program, there should exist some way to make the function recover from breakdown automatically.
Please help.

I'm quite new in python and spider, so please give as detailed and thorough solutions as possible.

Comment: Does the site you're accessing have any kind of policy for rate limiting requests? The code that you have here looks totally fine so I'm thinking it might be something outside your control

Comment: It's really weird that there is no policy for rate limiting requests. Most weird is that I can manually restart the function and it works good, but it can't automatically recover from breakdown.

Comment: I looked into the requests code and it's creating a new session per request made, meaning: you're creating a completely new HTTP connection every time you call the url. So its not your http connection thats dying. Have you been able to check the http requests that fail to check for a failure reason/content?

Comment: @Greg I think it's not http requests problem, but the python threading mudular. Now I abandon threading and turn to APScheduler to start the 4 spiders simutanously by add_interval_job. It works quite well.

Comment: well.. that might have been useful to know about in the ticket.